# Is there a way to write an `if case` statement as an expression?

Tags: swift

Consider this code:

```
enum Type {
    case Foo(Int)
    case Bar(Int)

    var isBar: Bool {
        if case .Bar = self {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

That's gross. I would like to write something like this instead:

```
enum Type {
    case Foo(Int)
    case Bar(Int)

    var isBar: Bool {
        return case .Bar = self
    }
}
```

But such a construct does not seem to exist in Swift, or I cannot find it.

Since there's data associated with each case, I don't think it's possible to implement the `~=` operator (or any other helper) in a way that's equivalent to the above expression. And in any case, `if case` statements exist for free for all enums, and don't need to be manually implemented.

Thus my question: is there any more concise/declarative/clean/idiomatic way to implement `isBar` than what I have above? Or, more directly, is there any way to express `if case` *statements* as Swift *expressions*?

Comment: You might find these comments regarding switch and if/else statements becoming _expressions_ posted in the "swift evolution forum" useful: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/commonly_proposed.md.  So, unfortunately, the answer is "no".

Comment: For those still following, there's been some discussion about a similar topic here: https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-even-smarter-keypaths/5923/2

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2:**
Another workaround... Create a `var` that returns an `Int` ONLY based on the case, then use a static (or instance, I thought static looked cleaner) method to test equivalence of just the case. It won't clash with `Equatable`, you don't have to overload an operator (unless you want to replace the static method with one), and you also wouldn't have to create separate `var isFoo`, `var isBar`, etc.

I know you used this example to ask a more generic question (how can I use 'if case' as an expression?) but if that's not possible, this may be a valid workaround. I apologize if this treats "the symptoms" not "the problem"

```
enum Something{
    case Foo(Int)
    case Bar(Int)

    static func sameCase(a: Something, b: Something) -> Bool {
        return a.caseValue == b.caseValue
    }

    var caseValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case .Foo(_):
            return 0
        case .Bar(_):
            return 1
        }
    }

    //if necessary
    var isBar: Bool {
        return Something.sameCase(self, b: Something.Bar(0))
    }
}

Something.sameCase(.Bar(0), b: .Foo(0)) // false
Something.sameCase(.Bar(1), b: .Foo(2)) // false
Something.sameCase(.Foo(0), b: .Foo(0)) // true
Something.sameCase(.Bar(1), b: .Bar(2)) // true


Something.Bar(0).isBar // true
Something.Bar(5).isBar // true
Something.Foo(5).isBar // false
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Ok, so this seems to work. If you overload the == operator to ignore values and return true only when both enums are the same case, you can pass any value in your isFoo method and still determine the type.

I'm assuming you will need to customize this function to accommodate the the associated values, but it seems like a step in the right direction

```
enum Something {
    case Foo(Int)
    case Bar(Int)

    var isFoo: Bool {
        return self == .Foo(0) // number doesn't matter here... see below
    }
}

func ==(a: Something, b: Something) -> Bool {
    switch (a,b) {
    case (.Bar(_), .Bar(_)):
        return true
    case (.Foo(_), .Foo(_)):
        return true
    default:
        return false

    }
}

let oneFoo = Something.Foo(1)
let twoFoo = Something.Foo(2)
let oneBar = Something.Bar(1)
let twoBar = Something.Bar(2)

oneFoo == twoFoo // true
oneFoo == oneFoo // true
oneFoo == oneBar // false
oneFoo == twoBar // false
```

**OLD:**

You can use `self` and the `case` name to directly check which case it is, you don't have to use the `case` keyword. Hopefully this will work for your situation:

```
enum Something{
    case Foo(Int)
    case Bar(Int)

    var isFoo: Bool {
        switch self {
        case Foo:
            return true
        case Bar:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the way the op declared their enums: `case Foo(Int)` and `case Bar(Int)`.

Comment: I've edited the answer to use a switch statement. Are you trying to do this all in one line?

Comment: Flaw: this is more code, is semantically identical to the undesirable approach, and scales worse. It doesn't solve the problem of a pattern-matching expression, it just uses a different type of statement.

Comment: Your original idea before edit is more in the right direction, but it also doesn't solve the problem -- you must explicitly define conformance to `Equatable` for it to work, and it as @JAL pointed out it doesn't work with associated data.

Comment: New edit definitely takes more code, but makes the enum cleaner.. plus, I'm assuming you're already implementing the == overload anyway?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't override `==` that way, since that breaks the contract of `Equatable` (which might be significant for some types). But sure, it's possible to implement something kinda like the `~=` operator that only does case comparison, *assuming* your associated types have "default vales" that you can come up with. But what if it's `case Bar(UIView)`? Or something even more radical -- this solution doesn't work in general. This type of solution is what I meant in the paragraph beginning "Since there's data...", but I suppose it wasn't too clear.

Answer (score 1):

So, there is a neater way, but requires a 3rd-party package: [CasePaths](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-case-paths)

The idea is they work similarly to `KeyPath`s, and they come with a `/` operator to trigger it. There is also a `~=` operator to check if a `CasePath` matches an instance.

So, you can achieve something like your original example like so:

```
import CasePaths

enum Type {
    case Foo(Int)
    case Bar(Int)

    var isBar: Bool {
        /Self.Bar ~= self
    }
}
```

You can also get the value:

```
extension Type {
    /// Returns the `Int` if this is a `Bar`, otherwise `nil`.
    var barValue: Int? {
        (/Self.Bar).extract(from: self)
    }
}
```

You can do several other useful things with `CasePath`s as well, such as extracting the `Foo` values in an array of `Type` values:

```
let values: [Type] = [.Foo(1), .Bar(2), .Foo(3), .Foo(4), .Bar(5)]
let foos = values.compactMap(/Type.Foo) // [1, 3, 4]
let bars = values.compactMap(/Type.Bar) // [2, 5]
```

I'm sure there is somewhat of a performance cost, but it may not be an issue in your context.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar wondering, and I kept searching for some work arounds about this, and landed on this page.  I came up with code like this to compromise.

```
fileprivate enum TypePrimitive {
    case foo
    case bar
}

enum Type {
    case foo(Int)
    case bar(Int)
    fileprivate var primitiveType: TypePrimitive {
        switch self {
        case .foo(_): return .foo
        case .bar(_): return .bar
        }
    }
    var isFoo: Bool { self.primitiveType == .foo }
    var isBar: Bool { self.primitiveType == .bar }
}
```

I hope Apple will provide better solution by adding some features in Swift language.

Answer (score -7):

Are you looking for the `?` operator  ?

[documentation is here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) under the **Ternary Conditional Operator** title.

Comment: I don't think that you read the question fully. I'm almost looking for the opposite of this. There is no unary `?case` operator. This works in the general case of lifting `if` statements into expressions, but does not allow lifting `if case` expressions.

Comment: I think youre missing the fact that you can chain it. like: result = a > b ? "Greater" : a < b ? "Smaller" : "Equal"

Comment: What does the associativity of the operator have to do with `if case` expressions?

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu your answer is more likely to be accepted if you post example code in it :)