# Can I use case enum comparison as a boolean expression?

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enum with associated values:

```
enum SessionState {
    ...
    case active(authToken: String)
    ...
}
```

I can use `case let` to compare enum cases with associated values:

```
if case .active = session.state {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

But can I directly return the `case` as a bool expression? Something like:

```
// Error: Enum 'case' is not allowed outside of an enum
return (case .active = session.state)
```

A simple comparison doesn’t work either:

```
// Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SessionState' and '_'
return (session.state == .active)
```

Comment: No, you cannot, only with "if", "guard", or "for". Not even with "where".

Comment: Bummer. Is there a related discussion somewhere on the mailing list, a change proposal?

Comment: I don't know if this has been discussed on the Swift mailing lists,

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099325/test-enum-for-equality-in-for-where-clause.

Comment: Thank you! Very much, to be precise and get over the minimum comment length limit :–)

Comment: The minimum content length is there to prevent thank you posts in comments :-)

Comment: (I guess *d–oh!* comments are on the blacklist, too, then? I’ll see myself out.)

Comment: If you take a look at [the grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/condition-list), you can see that `case-condition­` is a part of `condition`, which is used in a `condition-list` which is then used in statements such as `if` and `guard`. So unfortunately you cannot use it as a lone expression.

Comment: Could we turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot (directly) use a `case` condition as a `Bool` expression. They are only accessible in statements such as `if`, `guard`, `while`, `for` etc.

This is detailed in the [language grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID428), with:

```
case-condition → case ­pattern­ initializer­
```

This is then used in a `condition`:

```
condition → expression |­ availability-condition |­ case-condition­ | optional-binding-condition
```

(where `expression` represents a `Bool` expression)

This is then used in `condition-list`:

```
condition-list → condition­ | condition ­, ­condition-list
```

­

which is then used in statements such as `if`:

```
if-statement → if­ condition-list­ code-block­ else-clause­ opt­
```

So you can see that unfortunately `case-condition` is not an expression, rather just a special condition you can use in given statements.

To pack it into an expression, you'll either have to use an immediately-evaluated closure:

```
return { if case .active = session.state { return true }; return false }()
```

Or otherwise write convenience computed properties on the `enum` in order to get a `Bool` in order  to check for a given case, as shown [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36222805/2976878).

Both of which are quite unsatisfactory. This [has been filed as an improvement request](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4644), but nothing has come of it yet (at the time of posting). Hopefully it's something that will be possible in a future version of the language.

Answer (score 0):

No, at this moment.
but may implement in the future.

https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-case-expressions-for-pattern-matching/20348

Comment: This is uncomfortably close to a "link-only" answer, which would not be considered an answer and likely be deleted. However I think there is an answer hidden here. Could you, in addition to the link, summarize what makes you expect this and any indicator of an estimated time of availability.