# Make an enum with two cases convertible to Bool in Swift

Tags: swift, enums, type-conversion, boolean

I have an enum that I use for text validation defined as follows:

```
enum Validity {
    case valid
    case invalid(reason: String)
}
```

My `TextValidator` has a function that checks a text input and returns a `Validity`:

```
func validate(_ string: String) -> Validity
```

which is convenient because in case of an error I can display the validation failure reason to the user without much effort.

In many cases, however, I simply need a boolean check if the string is valid – for example for enabling / disabling a submit button. The code that I'm using for this right now is:

```
let validity = validator.validate("user input string")
submitButton.isEnabled = (validity == .valid)
```

which is kind of bad to read and thus, I would prefer to write something like:

```
let isValid: Bool = validator.validate("user input string")
submitButton.isEnabled = isValid
```

or shorter:

```
submitButton.isEnabled = validator.validate("user input string")
```

As a "quick fix" I have defined a computed boolean property `isValid` on my `Validity` enum so I can at least write:

```
submitButton.isEnabled = validator.validate("user input string").isValid
```

but it seems kind of verbose to me to append `.isValid` to a validation result and I would very much prefer to directly check the validity and treat it as a boolean when used in a context that expects a boolean via type inference.

So my question is:

#### Is there a way to make an enum implicitly convertible to `Bool` in Swift?

*Or if not:* Can you think of another approach that retains the advantages of both – the Bool and the enum type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use case enum comparison as a boolean expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391346/can-i-use-case-enum-comparison-as-a-boolean-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by overloading your `validate` function to also return `Bool`.

```
enum Validity {
    case valid
    case invalid(reason: String)
}

// Example validate function
func validate(_ string: String) -> Validity {
    if string.count < 5 {
         return .valid
    } else {
        return .invalid(reason: "String too long")
    }
}

// Overloaded function which returns Bool
func validate(_ string: String) -> Bool {
    let validity: Validity = validate(string)
    if case .valid = validity {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

// Swift expects the result of validate to be a Bool, so it calls the
// (String) -> Bool version of validate
let b1: Bool = validate("this")
print(b1)
```

> ```
> true
> ```

```
// Here, the result of validate is used in an if, so Swift is expecting
// a Bool result and calls the (String) -> Bool version of validate
if validate("this is a test") {
    print("the string is valid")
} else {
    print("the string is invalid")
}
```

> ```
> the string is invalid
> ```

```
let v: Validity = validate("what about this one?")
switch v {
case .valid:
    print("valid")
case .invalid(let reason):
    print("invalid: \(reason)")
}
```

> ```
> invalid: String too long
> ```

Comment: Thanks! It's a good answer in that it fulfills the requirements specified in my question. I'm not sure, however, if the general idea of doing this is good as other developers might get a little confused when reading the code. Another downside is that you cannot use any of these two `validate(_:)` functions without providing type context, i.e. `let validity = validate("sometext")` would raise a compile time error because the compiler doesn't know which function to call. I guess there is no way to define one of the overloaded functions as the preferred / default one?

Comment: There is no way to define the preferred one that I am aware of. You're right about the downsides.  In the end, your `.isValid` isn't all that bad.